# Change EndPoint to NuSoap Client

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

English is not my native language so please be patient.

I need to report the status of some mail deliverys to another company trough WebService. I'm using PHP+NuSoap, I'm new to PHP and this library help me to keep it simple, my code looks like this:

```
require_once '../nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';

Class Cliente{

    var $server;

    public function __construct(){        
        $this->server = 'https://the-other-company.com/services/PksiryacwebMgrTarjetasSubsi?wsdl';
    }

    function client_process($data){

        $cliente = new nusoap_client($this->server,'wsdl','','','','');

        $err = $cliente->getError();
        if ($err) { echo 'Error en Constructor' . $err ; }

        $response = $cliente->call('prwebActualizaCorresponden',$data,'','', false,true);  //OK

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Where `$data` is an array of strings and the WebService Server is suposed to return a response (always), but instead doesn't reply anything.

When I called the WebService administrator, he told me that test it using SoapUI, then I find the problem is with the WSDL, because is pointing to an private IP addres (172.20.8.152) which can only be accesed from inside the other company LAN, instead the IP I was told to work (the-other-company.com).

```
<wsdl:service name="PksiryacwebMgr_Tarjetas_SubsiService">
      <wsdl:port binding="impl:PksiryacwebMgr_Tarjetas_SubsiSoapBinding" name="PksiryacwebMgr_Tarjetas_Subsi">
         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://172.20.8.152/services/PksiryacwebMgrTarjetasSubsi"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In SoapUI this problem is easy to tackle setting another **EndPoint** with the right IP, but how to do this in NuSoap?

Edit: A workaround would be to make my own wsdl/xml, but that's not the idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function setEndpoint, it's defined arround the line 7873 of nusoap.php:

```
    /**
 * sets the SOAP endpoint, which can override WSDL
 *
 * @param    string $endpoint The endpoint URL to use, or empty string or false to prevent override
 * @access   public
 */
function setEndpoint($endpoint)
{
    $this->debug("setEndpoint(\"$endpoint\")");
    $this->forceEndpoint = $endpoint;
}
```

In your test code could be used by this way:

```
require_once '../nusoap/lib/nusoap.php';

Class Cliente{
    var $server;
    var $endPoint;

    public function __construct(){        
        $this->server = 'https://the-other-company.com/services/PksiryacwebMgrTarjetasSubsi?wsdl';
        $this->endPoint = 'http://172.20.8.152/services/PksiryacwebMgrTarjetasSubsi';
    }

    function client_process($data){

        $cliente = new nusoap_client($this->server,'wsdl','','','','');
        $cliente->setEndpoint($this->endPoint);

        $err = $cliente->getError();
        if ($err) { echo 'Error en Constructor' . $err ; }

        $response = $cliente->call('prwebActualizaCorresponden',$data,'','', false,true);  //OK

        return $response;
    }
}
```